# How to speed up iterating over pandas DF and pull certain column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that can vary in length but will have ~100 columns and anywhere from 40,000 to a couple hundred thousand rows.

We are analyzing automotive engine cylinder events, so each row is a cylinder event and the columns are various statistics associated with these events such as kurtosis, std deviation, etc.  Each of these stats have 8 columns (one for each cylinder).  The example table below shows just one of these statistics but the others follow the same pattern.

| timestamps | Analysis_Cylinder | kurtosis_Tree[CylinderA] | kurtosis_Tree[CylinderB] | kurtosis_Tree[CylinderC] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | CylinderA | 1.7876638174057 | 2.2034273147583 | 1.73644828796387 |
| 0.0060031 | CylinderB | 1.7876638174057 | 2.2034273147583 | 1.73644828796387 |
| 0.0120792 | CylinderC | 1.7876638174057 | 2.2034273147583 | 1.73644828796387 |

This data is then fed into a decision tree function.  And the stats that correspond to the "Analysis Tree" column are copied to a "results" dataframe.

My problem is that it is currently taking ~5+ minutes to get through the whole dataframe.  I know .iterrows is not the fastest but I'm not sure what a faster way to do this would be.

Here's my current python code:

```
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns=('Timestamp', 'Analysis Cylinder', 'Kurtosis', 'IMEP', 'Finite Difference', 'Fundamental Frequency', 'Standard Deviation', 'Actual Tree Node', 'Expected Tree Node', 'Expected Class'))
    for index, rows in stats.iterrows():
        data = []
        #data_columns = ['Timestamp', 'Analysis Cylinder', 'Actual Tree Node', 'Expected Tree Node', 'Expected Class']
        analysis_cyl = rows['Analysis_Cylinder']
        expected_tree, expected_class = get_expected_decision_tree(analysis_cyl, num_nodes, calibrations, rows)
        tree_node_label = [col for col in rows.index if ('TreeNodeID_Cyl' in col and analysis_cyl in col)]

        kurtosis_col = [col for col in rows.index if ('Kurtosis' in col and 'Tree' in col and analysis_cyl in col)]
        kurtosis_value = rows[kurtosis_col[0]]

        imep_col = [col for col in rows.index if ('IMEP' in col and 'Tree' in col and analysis_cyl in col)]
        imep_value = rows[imep_col[0]]

        fd_col = [col for col in rows.index if ('FiniteDiff' in col and 'Tree' in col and analysis_cyl in col)]
        fd_value = rows[fd_col[0]]

        freq_col = [col for col in rows.index if ('FundamentalFrequency' in col and 'Tree' in col and analysis_cyl in col)]
        freq_value = rows[freq_col[0]]

        sd_col = [col for col in rows.index if ('Std' in col and 'Tree' in col and analysis_cyl in col)]
        sd_value = rows[sd_col[0]]

        data = [rows['timestamps'], analysis_cyl, kurtosis_value, imep_value, fd_value, freq_value, sd_value, rows[tree_node_label][0], expected_tree, expected_class]
        result.loc[index] = data
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried running your code but got an error `KeyError: 'Analysis_Cylinder'`. With just a few tweaks I think you'll have a simple and reproducible input, code, and output that will help people answer this question

Comment: Without looking at it too closely, you will probably need to vectorize `get_expected_decision_tree`. Can you run cProfile on this to check if `get_expected_decision_tree` is slow or this loop?

Comment: isn't `iterrows` a bad practice, especially when performance is a concern?

Answer (score 0):

1. Divide your df into *N* sub-dfs, keeping only rows and columns relevant to one Cylinder.
2. Apply your for-loop for each sub-df. In the for-loop, you can get rid of all `[col for col in .....]` because now only relevant columns exist in the sub-df.
3. Refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues) for performance discussion around `iterrows`. `itertuples` can be your immediate improvement, but vectorization is certainly the best, but it depends on `get_expected_decision_tree` which is a black box to us so I cannot comment further.
4. as an alternative, to use `apply` instead of `iterrows`, you may restructure your df so that you have one column for one stat (instead of 3 columns for the same `kurtosis_Tree`). It is also equivalent to `pd.concat` the resulting sub-dfs from my step 1 above.